# How to export excel data using XMLMap and EPPlus

Tags: c#, xml, epplus

I was wondering if someone can assist me in achieving the C# code below in either EPPlus or OpenOffice XML:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

string excelFileName = "Sample.xlsx";

string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string excelFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(currentDirectory, excelFileName);

app.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
string xmlContent = string.Empty;

// Use the map (XSD inside the Excel file)
app.ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps[1].ExportXml(out xmlContent);
app.Workbooks.Close();
```

Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application requires installation of Microsoft Office on the server. Is there any way around this other than installing Microsoft Engine?. Basically how to read XMLMap without office.Interop?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need XmlMap? If you want to generate an xlsx file from data you can use eg `sheet.LoadFromDataTable()`, `sheet.LoadFromCollection()` and lately `sheet.LoadFromDataReader()`  to fill a sheet from a DataTable, object collection or DbDataReader directly.

Comment: Because I am embedding XMLMap within xlsx and when I want to export I want to export based on schema app.ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps[1].ExportXml(out xmlContent);